# Issue with encrypt and decrypt a word docx file in php

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I tried to use php mcrypt TripleDES  for encryption for **docx** format files.

When i tried to decrypt the file, i am getting the error as follows.

> The Office Open XML file file_name cannot be opened because there are
>   problems with the contents.

Here is the below code

```
function Encrypt($source,$key,$iv) {
      $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', 'cbc', '');
      mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
      $result = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $source);
      mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
      return $result;
}


function Decrypt($source,$key,$iv) {

  $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', 'cbc', ''); 
  mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
  $result = mdecrypt_generic($cipher, $source);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
  return $result;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Decrypt` isn't returning anything, is that a typo?

Comment: Yep its a typo, Really sorry for that... actually it will return $result

Comment: Did you try without encryption first, twice returning $source? To exclude trivial secondary errors. mcrypt_module_close() is missing.

Comment: Not the cause for your issue, but you're misusing the IV. You should not pass it to `Encrypt`, but `Encrypt` should generate a new one each time, and prepend it to the output. And `Decrypt` should read it from the output.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You don't show the your IO related code. Please post a full program that exhibits the problem. I suspect that the file gets treated as text instead of binary somewhere.

Comment: The Encrypt function  padded the data with "\0" to make sure the length of the data is complete the block size. But when i try to decrypt its removing all "\0" from data which causes error... For eg:the data length is  21...inorder to compete the block size 8... it will add "\0\0\0"... but when i decrypt it will remove total block...it will show the length as 16

Comment: Can i send the code to you?pls give me your mail id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been waiting for the solution more than 4  months.
Finally i found some valuable answer in google. Now i have fixed it by using below link.

http://www.howwhywhat.in/how-to-implement-common-file-encryption-and-decryption-between-c-and-php/

Best part is ,it has live examples too:)