# How to make a file encrypt and decrypt with TripleDes in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, tripledes

I couldn't find enough resource about this subject and i need to learn how can i encrypt and decrypt file using TripleDes in PHP (while uploading it should encrypt the file and while downloading the file it should decrypt).

Also i found some examples but i couldn't implement it
http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548386/issue-with-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-word-docx-file-in-php

Thanks for your interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to encrypt a string:

```
$buffer = $file; 
// get the amount of bytes to pad
$extra = 8 - (strlen($buffer) % 8);
// add the zero padding
if($extra > 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $extra; $i++) {
        $buffer .= "\0";
    }
}
// very simple ASCII key and IV
$key = "passwordDR0wSS@P6660juht";
$iv = "password";
// hex encode the return value
$encrypted_file = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $buffer, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);
```

And this to decrypt it:

```
$decrypted_file = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $encrypted_file, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
```

Comment: You could just do `$buffer = $file . str_repeat("\0", 8 - (strlen($file) % 8));`. Also, shouldn't you remove the NUL bytes after decryption?

Comment: thanks, i'm trying now. but that $output variable equals with what? is it encrypted file for download?

Comment: My bad, that should have been $encrypted_file